# How can i make my workbook expire on a certain date?

Tags: vba, excel

I am sending out some trial worksheets for work although these will resemble the real things at some point so i dont want people using them eg in a years time.

I want my code to delete the contents of a sheet in the active workbook as this worksheets acts as a validation which if i remove will stop access to the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim MyDate As Date
Dim Today As Date

MyDate = #1/5/2015#
Today = Now()

If ActiveWorkbook = Workbooks("SALARY CALCULATOR BETA1.xlsm") Then
   If Today > MyDate Then
    Worksheets("Lock").Range("A1:T115").Select
    Selection.Clear

End If
End If
End Sub
```

The Code returns "Object doesn't support object or property"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'd leave selecting out of the code. E.g. `Worksheets("Lock").Range("A1:T115").Clear` And I prefer using ISO standard dates, just to be sure. `2015-05-01` in your case. Other than that, your code seems to be OK.

Comment: Sorry, the code currently doesn't work i cant figure out how to fix it to run properly eg. on a certain date it deletes the contents of a sheet

Comment: whats going to prevent the user from copying and pasting the content into a new spreadsheet workbook that doesn't contain your VBA content?

Comment: The Workbook itself is extensive and the contents that are cleared from the vba act as a password recognition which are automatically "veryhidden" so once they open the work book on that date their password wont be valid so they won't be able to access the documents features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just compare two objects (workbooks in your case) like that. Try comparing their names.

So instead of:

```
If ActiveWorkbook = Workbooks("SALARY CALCULATOR BETA1.xlsm") Then
```

use this:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "SALARY CALCULATOR BETA1.xlsm" Then
```

Or, to avoid confusion from renaming, use this:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
```

ThisWorkbook always means the workbook running the macro (which basically means the workbook containing the macro.)

**Edit**

Here is a one-liner that works for me:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   If Date > #1/5/2016# Then Worksheets("Lock").Range("A1:T115").Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: That returns an object defined error but i see what your'e saying, is it not the selection part of the code from there that confuses things?

Comment: Try my edit, with the `thisworkbook.name`. Which row produces the error?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you need that If statement at all. After opening a workbook, that workbook will be the active one, you you can just go ahead and delete the unnecessary data.

Comment: See my edit for a simple solution that works for me.

Comment: The error is from  'Worksheets("Lock").Range("A1:T115").Select
    Selection.Clear'

Comment: You can only select cells on the active sheet. Try avoiding selecting them, just clear them. See my edited answer for example.

Comment: Sorry just added your edit and it works perfectly. Thanks